# Meaning of ''とね''

Tags: translation, particle-と, questions, anime

I was reading a novel and then I saw this following sentence:

''でも、まぁ草薙にはいろいろ迷惑かけてるし、なんか今日はサービスしてあげてもいいかなぁ、とね''

What's the function of とね?

Comment: it feels to me like and abbreviation of と思うね. a kind of rhetorical question, “don’t you think/agree?”

Comment: @A.Ellett 思うね practically doesn't mean "don't you agree?" but "I think that way after all".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's filler ね, which is semantically meaningless, inserted after と, which, on the other hand, some predicate would follow if it was not omitted.

…いいかなぁと思ってやったんです (I did it because I thought it would be nice ...)↓

…いいかなぁとね、思ってね、やったんです↓

…いいかなぁとね…